# How to set up DBAppender with log4j in JBoss5?

Tags: database, log4j, jboss5.x, logback

I would like to be able to set up my clustered JBoss5 instances to write log4j messages to a database. I am trying to use a [DBAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) (rather than a JDBCAppender, for the reasons given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364322/log-to-a-database-using-log4j)).

Has anyone done this? As of now, I've added an `<appender>` tag to jboss-log4j.xml and put the logback-classic-0.9.17.jar file in every jar-filled folder in my JBoss directory, but I'm still getting a ClassNotFoundException when JBoss tries to look for it on startup.

ANY tips/examples you can give me might be helpful, either in getting me farther in this direction, or pointing me in a better direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting an answer from David Lloyd in [this thread](http://community.jboss.org/message/538349#538349) on the Jboss forums:

> (...) The real question would be "how does one configure JBoss AS 5.1.0 to use LogBack?".  The answer to that is, one doesn't; log4j is the only supported logging backend in all AS 5.x releases.

Seems pretty clear: you can't configure JBoss to use logback and, as a consequence, its `DBAppender`.

So I'm afraid you'll have to go the `JDBCAppender` way (Log4j) if you really want to log to a database. But I would think twite about this (or at least bench it seriously).

Just in case, maybe have a look at [JBLOGGING-6](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBLOGGING-6).