# What is the best way to log to SQL Server from Java EE

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic

I have a web service Jax-RS running in Weblogic. I have a need to logg the calls made to the service.

What is the best way to log to SQL Server from a java application?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "best" mean to you?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Better than Log4J JDBCAppender :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked in a very simlilar fashion a little while ago.
See here for the original: [Log to a database using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364322/log-to-a-database-using-log4j)

The accepted answer points to the **DBAppender** by logback.
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking for the best way, and if Log4J is not a strong requirement, my suggestion would be to use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and its [`DbAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender). That's the best way :)

Last time I checked, the [`JDBCAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html) from Log4J was still not satisfying and if you can't use logback, you might prefer some third party implementation. See the links below for details:

- http://www.boky.cc/2010/02/03/jdbcappender-for-log4j/
- http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/ (older)

Comment: Can logback be dynamically turned on and off once the app is live?

Comment: @John Yes, logback can be configured to [reload](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan) its configuration. You can also configure it at runtime via [JMX](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html).