# Reconnect to DB within log4j

Tags: log4j

If I have a JDBCAppender configured to throw log messages to MySQL
and, while my system is up I restart the database is it reconnect to DB?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this use case occur over this past weekend. My database is hosted by Amazon AWS. It rolled over my log database and all of the instances logging to that database via the Log4j JDBC Appender stopped logging. I bounced one of the apps and it resumed logging.

So the answer to this question, through experience, appears to be **No**.

If the database goes down and comes back online, the JDBC appender does not reconnect automatically.

**edit**

JDBCAppender [getConnection](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/xref/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html#247) might be overridden to fix.

Comment: Perhaps override `getConnection()` to ensure the connection is valid. If not create a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

JDBCAppender in log4j 1.2.15 has following code

```java
protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
      if (!DriverManager.getDrivers().hasMoreElements())
         setDriver("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

      if (connection == null) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, databaseUser,
                    databasePassword);
      }

      return connection;
  }
```

so if connection is not null, but is broken (needs reconnect) log4j will return broken connection to its logic, and executing statement which does logging to db will fail.

Not a workaround, but a proper solution is to replace log4j with logback: see related answer: [Log to a database using log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364322/log-to-a-database-using-log4j/1366684#1366684)