# Logs queue in multithreaded application which dump information to DB (server side application)?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, logging, server-side

Could you advise me how to implements queue in multithreaded application.

I have to register events in my application in queue (events from all users) which I flush and save to database every 100 events to improve performance. I don't want save database log for every single user commit. I suppose commit e.x. every 100 events to database will be faster that 100 single commits. I have three ideas:

- use ThreadLocal
- use queue for single user
- use synchronized LinkedList and flush from time to time or every number of events

Do you have any other ideas? I don't use log4j because I have to save log to database - not to file, which method will the best?

Comment: No need to implement it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364322/log-to-a-database-using-log4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a BlockingQueue implementation like `ArrayBlockingQueue`.  Any thread can safely add an event to the queue, and one (or more) threads can safely remove elements from the queue.  Have a background thread wait for events on the queue (`BlockingQueue.take()`).  Once you collect 100 elements, do your stuff.

Comment: I implemented that using BlockingQueue, it's working on production and it's very performance. Thanks.