# Java Application Cluster Server and log files

Tags: java, cluster-computing, application-server

Application is running on the cluster of servers.

I am seeking the clarification for two questions.

1.Do the Application(ear) runs also on Admin server or only in the node server?Am i right to say that admin server is used to start ,stop ,load balance,failover in and between the node servers?

2.What is the standard practice to write the log file?for instance if there is any production issue, do we need to log in to each node (different linux server) to check for the log files.In one of my experience, i used to login to each server for the logs for the particular error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Admin server

An "admin server" is usually a regular node, that was selected for handling application **deployment** over the cluster. Most likely, you can pick any node for this task, since the changes can be propagated to all other servers automatically (assuming a farm deployer is available).

**Load balancing** and **failover** are completely independent from application deployment. Relying on a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) is usually the best way to acheive those ([nginx](http://nginx.com/) for example).

### Clustered logging

You can aggregate your logs in a regular file on a designated server. Use [SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) and a [dedicated log4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender), if that's your logging framework.

You can also store your logs in a shared database. An [appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364322/log-to-a-database-using-log4j) is available for this as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering.So Admin server is meant only for the application deployment across the nodes and it has nothing to do with Load Balancing and failover.My myth busted.